# Dynamic query to get dynamic columns from rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have been trying to create PL/SQL statement that creates a dynamic query in order to get dynamic columns. Since I don't have much idea about these Oracle PL/SQL statements; I am confused about few things.

Is it mandatory to have stored procedure for creating dynamic queries ?

The following query does not throw any error and even results nothing. What I am trying to do in the following query is to get sum of **FKOD_AMOUNT** according to **FKBAB_SOURCE_ID** which is foreign key for **PFS_SOURCE_ID**.

```
    declare
    sql_query varchar2(3000) := 'select FKOM_OFFICE_ID,FKBAM_BUDGET_ID ';
    begin
        for x in (select distinct PFS_SOURCE_ID,PFS_SOURCE_ENG from PBS_FC_SOURCE WHERE PFS_UPPER_SOURCE_ID!=0 )
        loop
            sql_query := sql_query ||
                ' , sum(case when FKBAB_SOURCE_ID = '||x.PFS_SOURCE_ID||' then FKOD_AMOUNT ELSE 0 end) as '||x.PFS_SOURCE_ENG;
                dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        end loop;
        sql_query := sql_query || ' FROM FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_DTL
        JOIN FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_MST ON FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_MST.FKOM_OFFICE_MST_ID=FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_DTL.FKOD_OFFICE_MST_ID
        JOIN FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_DTL ON FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_DTL.FKBAD_BUDGET_ALLOC_DTL_ID=FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_DTL.FKOD_BUDGET_ALLOC_AD_ID
        JOIN FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_MST ON FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_MST.FKBAM_BUDGET_ALLOC_ID=FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_DTL.FKBAB_BUDGET_ALLOC_ID
        JOIN PBS_FC_BUDGET ON PBS_FC_BUDGET.PFB_BUDGET_ID=FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_MST.FKBAM_BUDGET_ID
        GROUP BY FKOM_OFFICE_ID,FKBAM_BUDGET_ID ';
        dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
    end;
```

How can I execute 'sql_query' ?

Comment: @bluefeet : can you help on this ? Moderators closed my previous question.

Comment: You can do it using `execute immediate sql_query`. But where do you want the result go?

Comment: where do you want the result go means ? Can't I run get results on the same page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an answer(removed my comments), this is pl/sql, not a select statement, so you can't just run it.

With `execute immediate` you can use `INTO` clause to store the results into some variables or arrays.

But you may make the query a cursor, put the cursor into a pipelined function and then

```
select * from table(your_pipelined_function)
```

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Comment: [http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php)  [http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_pipe_functions.html](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_pipe_functions.html) [http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/exec_immediate.html](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/exec_immediate.html)